# How to print the first true and first false in python

Tags: python-3.x, read.csv

I have a set with time and each row either has a value of true or false and I want to print out the first row of true, then skip until it becomes false and print that alternating between those through the whole file

[image]

this is just an example of the set that I have the true values represent if the speed and distance to an object is less than a given number

What I want it to print

[image]
any ideas on how to do this in python

Comment: Set a variable (`current_bool`) to `None`. On each line, check whether `bool` is different to `current_bool`. If it is, print the line. After making the comparison, **and on every line**, set `current_bool` to be the value of `bool`. This will only print those lines where the value of `bool` changes

Comment: how would this work in code? I'm new to this, I can understand the logic in your answer but I struggle to code it

Comment: Just added a code sample for you.

Answer (score 1):

I've taken your data and converted it in to a `list` of Python `dict` structures. You could easily use a list of lists (`[ [..], [..], ... ]`) but a dict makes it easier to imagine when starting out

```
data = [
    {'id': 1, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": True},
    {'id': 2, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": True},
    {'id': 3, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": True},
    {'id': 4, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": False},
    {'id': 5, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": False},
    {'id': 6, "time": "10/03/2022 01:20", "bool": False},
    {'id': 7, "time": "10/03/2022 15:13", "bool": True},
    {'id': 8, "time": "10/03/2022 15:13", "bool": True},
    {'id': 9, "time": "10/03/2022 15:13", "bool": False},
    {'id': 10, "time": "10/03/2022 15:13", "bool": True}
]

current_bool=None
for row in data:
    if current_bool != row['bool']:
        print(row)
    current_bool=row['bool']
```

The output is:

```
{'id': 1, 'time': '10/03/2022 01:20', 'bool': True}
{'id': 4, 'time': '10/03/2022 01:20', 'bool': False}
{'id': 7, 'time': '10/03/2022 15:13', 'bool': True}
{'id': 9, 'time': '10/03/2022 15:13', 'bool': False}
{'id': 10, 'time': '10/03/2022 15:13', 'bool': True}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I was really trying to wrap my head around the coding bit and now it does make sense